# Convert range to string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need help converting a range to a usable string. I'm not 100% sure of what I need, because I have little VBA or VB.NET experience, but ultimately i want to take a bunch of cells like `B32` to `J52` and perform linest function on `C`-`J` (as y values) and `B` (as x value).

I think if I can learn to pop out a string that says `"Bxx:Jyy"` Then i'd be able to tell it do `linest(Cxx:Cyy, Bxx:Byy, true, false)`.

Is there an easier way to do this? Anyway, all I have right now is some code to get the range from the user (just got it from Google). If someone could just help me get the string like stated above, I think I can manage the rest.

```
Dim oRangeSelected As Range
Set oRangeSelected = Application.InputBox("Please select a range of cells!", _
                     "SelectARAnge Demo", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
```

Comment: Is the Range datatype like an Array with indices? If so, you could loop through the Range and append the selected values to a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you want the user selected range (not pre-existing selection), so

```
MsgBox oRangeSelected.Address
```

*[Update]
Actually, reading your question more closely, you can use ranges as is with LINEST, ie this sub gets a user range for X and Y and then feeds LINEST. The results are stored in an array, MyArr, which can be returned to the user.*

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oRangeSelected1 As Range
    Dim oRangeSelected2 As Range
    Dim myArr()
    Set oRangeSelected1 = Application.InputBox("Please select a X range of cells!", "Select X Demo", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    Set oRangeSelected2 = Application.InputBox("Please select a  Y range of cells!", "Select Y Demo", , Type:=8)
    If oRangeSelected1.Columns.Count + oRangeSelected2.Columns.Count > 2 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a single column range only"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If oRangeSelected1.Cells.Count <> oRangeSelected2.Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox "Ranges are of different length"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    myArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(oRangeSelected1, oRangeSelected2)
    MsgBox "slope is " & Format(myArr(1), "0.00") & " & intercept is " & Format(myArr(2), "0.00")
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. This worked by having a string = oRangeSelected.Address.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `Selected.Address` that will display your range as a string.

Comment: Tried doing that but instead i got $J$52....so it just picked up the cell that was selected last, not the entire range.